# Non puntual sequences are not an equicontinous family

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

Given a sequence $u_{n}$ of (non constant) functions in  $\mathcal{C}(\overline{B},\mathbb{R})$ with $\overline{B}$ the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then, is it true that if $u_{n}$ does not converge point-wise then it can't be equicontinous?

Comment: The title is about uniform continuity, but the body of the question is about equicontinuity. What are you really interested in?

Comment: My mistake, I'm gonna correct it.

Comment: A family of constant functions is (uniformly) equicontinuous. Does every sequence of constant functions converge?

Comment: roger that. What if the sequence is not constant? I will specify it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equicontinuity and boundedness imply a (uniformly) convergent subsequence. But equicontinuity does not imply pointwise convergence: If $a_n$ is a non-convergent sequence of reals, then the functions $f_n(x)=x+a_n$ are equicontinuous but do not converge pointwise.